# Jenkins get changes since last successful build when using global shared library

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

In my scripted pipeline, I want to get changes since last successful build and based on files which have changed I want to enable or disable some parts of the pipeline. I am using Global Shared Library which contains definitions of some additional steps and the whole pipeline. To print changes since last successful build I am using the following code:

```
def showChanges(def build) {
    if ((build != null) && (build.result != 'SUCCESS')) {
        def changeLogSets = build.rawBuild.changeSets
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
            def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
            for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def entry = entries[j]
                echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
                def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
                for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                    def file = files[k]
                    echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
                }
            }
        }
        showChanges(build.getPreviousBuild())
    }
}
```

However, when I do some change in global library then it prints just this change and not the change which happened on the main repository. The changeSet contains no info regarding files which have changed in the main cloned repository.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Jenkins loads all changes from all repositories and shared libraries referenced in your Pipeline into `rawBuild.changeSets`.  There's nothing you can really do about this except manually filter out repositories.  For instance, if you only want changes that come from the `my_awesome_repo` repository:

```
changeSets = rawBuild.changeSets.findAll { changeSet->
  try {
    changeSet.getBrowser().getRepoUrl() =~ /my_awesome_repo/
  } catch(groovy.lang.MissingMethodException e) {
    false // repository has no `browser` property
  }
}
```